# Get rid of table cellspacing?

Tags: html, css

See **[here](http://artotek.fi/mobiili_index.html)**.

I copied the codes from this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lt5Vx/3/)**, where it works just fine,
but on my site it shows huge gaps between the cells.

I've checked, there's nothing it overrides with.

```
        table td {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}


    td.fa-info-circle a
{
    display: block;
}

td.fa-phone a
{
    display: block;
}
```

[image: Gaps]

I've tried even [CSS reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset.css), but it was no use.

```
<table cellspacing="0px" style="border-spacing:0px">
    <tr>
        <td class="fa fa-info-circle"><a href="info.html">Tietoa Meistä</a></td>
        <td class="fa fa-phone"><a href="contact.html">Ota yhteyttä</a></td>
        <td class="fa fa-phone"><a href="contact.html">Ota yhteyttä</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

`fa-info-circle` calls the content from the class
`.fa-info-circle:before{content:"\f05a";}` which is the icon. Using FontAwesome.

Comment: it looks like you need to clear out the cache of your browser. I see it without gap and without images.

Comment: agreed with @bansi, i see no gap!!

Comment: Oh, thanks. Now the gap dissapearead. What do you mean no images?

Comment: side note: your css is not compatible with older browsers. first i tested with opera 12

Comment: I'm aware that below IE9 it's a mess.

Comment: @bansi Could you yet help me with this problem? http://artotek.fi/mobiili_index.html the link of the `td` element spreads so that it's clickable even outside the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to the question in the comment:

To fix the `<a>` element you can set the style to:

```
table td a {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 150px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Note: added fixed width for the element, and set margins to auto.

**Edit:** Changes as per comment (put image inside the link)

You need to do the following for this.

1. there is a style block for `table td a {` declared at line 1261. remove that block. it actually overrides the style declared at line 233
2. move the `fa` class to the span from the `td` tag.

   `<td><a href="info.html"><span class="fa fa-info-circle">Tietoa Meistä</span></a></td>`
3. change the `display: inline;` to `display: block;` for `table td a {` at line 236
4. change the `display: inline-block;` to `display: block;` at line 535 for class `.fa:before`.

**Edit 2:** Check the [Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/6JUbf/)

Comment: Thanks. Yet one problem; How can I expand the link over the icon? Tried setting height, but it expanded the link downwards.

Comment: you mean you want the image also to be part of the link (clickable)?

Comment: Exactly. How can I do that?

Comment: you may also need to add `table td a:hover{text-decoration: none;}` otherwise when you hover mouse you see an ugly line

Comment: Thanks for noting that, now what about the link to the icon?

Comment: i have edited my answer on what to do for the link to the icon.

Comment: I have added a fiddle to the answer. check if that is what you want?

Comment: One more thing, how can I seperate the icon from the text by a few pixels. Tried margin-bottom, but it didn't work.

Comment: you can use padding for class `.fa:before`. like `padding-bottom:20px;`. sorry, cannot update fiddle, working from my mobile now. can check back morning my time.